# What is the best pixel art application for Windows?

Tags: software-recommendation, windows, free, pixel-art

I'm trying to develop a game for smart phones. If I want to easily animate characters and output character-sheets. What's a good tool to use? There is so much software and I can't test all of them.

I don't want to use Photoshop because it is an indirect app to do that. My priorities are **free & friendly-user software**.

I'm not going to use Aseprite because this uses low-resolution window frames and fonts. Opinions vary on whether this sets the mood or gets in the way. Pixel-styled interface can be jarring.

Comment: To improve your question,  you can include the software you found when searching and explain why it is insufficient for your needs.

Comment: @JohnB I want to delete this Q, but this Q have an Answer. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the standalone editor at http://juliandescottes.github.io/piskel

You can use Piskel to do two things :

**spriting** : create retro-style sprites for games

**pixelart** : create crazy/pretty pixelart animations for fun !

**Offline version**:
Offline builds are available. More details in the [dedicated wiki page.](https://github.com/juliandescottes/piskel/wiki/Desktop-applications)

Comment: This software is very banal.

Comment: if you wanna a cool software you must buy it, free software are limited. http://www.aseprite.org/

Comment: i use it for a while, its easy to use ... thanks bro

Comment: the online version is better than offline ^_^